# JFace dialog with tabs

Tags: java, user-interface, tabs, eclipse-rcp, jface

I want to implement a tabbed dialog using JFace in my Eclipse RCE application. The content of one of the tabs should be a `ContainerSelectionDialog`, whose content looks like the following:

```
ContainerSelectionDialog dialog = new ContainerSelectionDialog(
        Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), container, true,
        "Please select target folder");
int open = dialog.open();
if (!(open == org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.OK))
    return null;
Object[] result = dialog.getResult();

IPath path = (IPath) result[0];
targetFolder = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().findMember(path);
containerPath = targetFolder.getLocation().toPortableString();
```

How is it possible to imlement a tabbed dialog and add the `ContainerSelectionDialog` to one of the tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. As you said, SelectionContainerDialog **is** a dialog. So you can't put its content to another dialog.

Take a look at SelectionContainerDialog class, the main content is handled by another class named **SelectionContainerGroup**. It may be a good place to start but,be careful with this class, it's **internal**.